# GCP emergency mode not available fs '/' is on read only

Tags: linux, google-cloud-platform

My fs '/' is on ro mode and I cannot umount it and remount it in rw.
All command like a simple `touch test` give me the error

```
fs is mounted on read only
```

I have tried to change the fstab to add rw, but I cannot edit any file in all fs '/', seems all fs is impacted

Can I boot on emergency mode to change the fstab ? I cannot found interactive console like in VMware.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can detach the disk from the VM using the below command:

```
gcloud compute instances detach-disk my-instance --disk=my-disk --zone us-central1-a
```

Attached it to any working VM as a secondary disk using the below command:

```
gcloud compute instances attach-disk example-instance  --disk DISK --zone us-central1-a
```

After mounting the disk you are able to change fstab file. After that detach from this vm again re-attach to original VM.

Comment: Thx I will try it.